# does RandomizedSearchCV automatically include the default model parameters that are passed to the constructor?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Let's say that I create a `RandomizedSearchCV` like so:

```
searcher = model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = RandomForestClassifier(),
                                            param_distributions = random_grid,
                                            n_iter = 20, # Number of parameter combinations to try
                                            cv     = 3,  # Number of folds for k-fold validation 
                                            n_jobs = -1) # Use all processors to compute in parallel
search = searcher.fit(x_train, y_train)
search.best_params_
```

`n_iter` tells us how many combinations the search will test. To me, it would be pretty important to know that as part of or in addition to the 20 combinations, that the default model parameters are included. Does anyone know if this is true or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are **not** (and arguably, it would be strange if this was the case).

The detailed values of the parameter combinations tried are returned in the attribute `cv_results_` of the fitted `RandomizedSearchCV` object. Adapting the example from the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) (using the default `n_iter = 10`), we get:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from scipy.stats import uniform

iris = load_iris()
logistic = LogisticRegression(solver='saga', tol=1e-2, max_iter=200,
                               random_state=0)
distributions = dict(C=uniform(loc=0, scale=4),
                      penalty=['l2', 'l1'])
clf = RandomizedSearchCV(logistic, distributions, random_state=0)

search = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
search.cv_results_
```

You can directly inspect the dictionary returned by `search.cv_results_`, or you can import it into a pandas dataframe for a more compact representation:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(search.cv_results_)
df['params']
# result:
0      {'C': 2.195254015709299, 'penalty': 'l1'}
1     {'C': 3.3770629943240693, 'penalty': 'l1'}
2     {'C': 2.1795327319875875, 'penalty': 'l1'}
3     {'C': 2.4942547871438894, 'penalty': 'l2'}
4       {'C': 1.75034884505077, 'penalty': 'l2'}
5    {'C': 0.22685190926977272, 'penalty': 'l2'}
6     {'C': 1.5337660753031108, 'penalty': 'l2'}
7     {'C': 3.2486749151019727, 'penalty': 'l2'}
8     {'C': 2.2721782443757292, 'penalty': 'l1'}
9       {'C': 3.34431505414951, 'penalty': 'l2'}
```

from where it is clear that the [default](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) value of `C=1.0` for `LogisticRegression` was **not** included in the search grid.

If you have any reason to assess the performance of the model with its default parameters, you should do it separately - arguably it is pretty straightforward (just 2 lines of code).